# Mongoose find if some condition from other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am trying to do the following Query in Mongo and I need some help.
I have 2 collections:

collection 1 - `users : {_id, name, lastname}`

collection 2 - `tutorial_finish : {user_id, completed}`

i want to select all users where their `name` is "John Doe" **and** the user **must not** **appear** in collection2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to "join" the data from both collections and then `$match` to check if array created by `$lookup` is empty:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { name: "John", lastname: "Doe" }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tutorial_finish",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "user_id",
            as: "tutorials"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { tutorials: [] }
    }
])
```